# How to align list items with icons?

Tags: c#, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an unordered list in my sidebar navigation and added icons in the left but the list item object seems without alignment in the left due to the icons different sizes.
Here's my example:

[image]

And here what I want:

[image]

Here the  code:
HTML(with ASP.Net MVC elements):

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar text-light bg-primary-darker">
        <ul>
            <li><a asp-action="Info" asp-controller="Dashboard"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
            <li><a asp-action="Invoices" asp-controller="Dashboard"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i>Invoices</a></li>
            <li><a asp-action="Customers" asp-controller="Dashboard"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>Customers</a></li>
            <li><a asp-action="Settings" asp-controller="Dashboard"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: -1px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #016fe6;
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-inline-start: 10px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li a i {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar li a:hover{
  color: rgb(189, 204, 204);
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using font awesome you can add `fa-fw` to them.
More info [Fixed Width Icons](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons)